# how to use inner text as object key

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with some code.I am making the keys of the object the value of the ID, but I need it to be the text of the label.

```
 function formObj(elems) {
  let form = {};
  let label = document.querySelectorAll('label')
  for(let elem of elems) {
    let key = elem.label.innerText;
    let val = elem.value;
    if(key && val)
      form[key] = key ==="age" ? Number(val) : val;
  }
  console.log(form)
  return form;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label for='name'>name</label>
    <input type='text' id='name' value="Harry"/>

    <label for='email'>email</label>
    <input type='email' id='email' value="harry@gmail.com"/>

    <label for='age'>age</label>
    <input type='text' id='age' value="22"/>
<form/>
```

I am unsure how to use `.innerHTML` to accomplish this.

Please help out

Comment: what does `elems` refer to in your code ?

Comment: @Nicolas the elements I am looping throug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the text of the label using `document.querySelector` and `innerText` to get the coresponding label, use it instead of `elem.id`

```js
let form = {};

let label = document.querySelectorAll('label');

let elements = document.querySelectorAll('form *')

const formObj = elems => {
  for (let elem of elems) {
    if (!elem.id) continue;
    let key = document.querySelector('label[for="' + elem.id + '"]').innerText;
    let val = elem.value;
    if (key && val)
      form[key] = key === "age" ? Number(val) : val;
  }

  console.log(form)
  return form;
}

formObj(elements);
```

```html
<form>
  <label for='name'>nameA</label>
  <input type='text' id='name' value="Harry" />

  <label for='email'>emailB</label>
  <input type='email' id='email' value="harry@gmail.com" />

  <label for='age'>ageC</label>
  <input type='text' id='age' value="22" />
  <form/>
```